# Property Binding in ASP.NET Core NOT binding property values to view model

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

Im trying to figure out why I am not able to send down a JSON object to my back-end api. Given the following code I can hit my api endpoint but the `Name: Test` is never making it to the controller:

Angular http request:

```
addSport(newSportType: SportType): Observable<SportType> {
const headers = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
        };
        return this.http.post<SportType>('/sport-type', JSON.stringify({ Name: 'Test' }), headers);
    }
```

[image]

My `TestViewModel` looks like this:

```
public class TestViewModel

    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there something basic I am missing in this set up?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Your JSON.stringify is give below output?
{
  "Name": "Test"
}

Comment: Yes, that is correct. That is what json stringify produces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**use `[FromBody]`**

```cs
public ... ([FromBody]TestViewModel newSportType)
{

}
```

Comment: While this is the correct answer, I suggest pasting the link of the document and the reason for adding `[FromBody]` to it.